# How to convert a webform into an ordered list?

Tags: 7, webforms

I've tried to preprocess a webform in order to convert the form items into an ordered list. My webform is composed of questions, and I want each question to be a enumerated list element.

[image]

The problem is that I cannot find where to convert the `<div>` following the `<form>` into an `<ol>`, and the next nested `<div>` into an `<li>`. After navigating webform's source code I could not find a function that says "give me all the webform elements", for example. It all seems to work in the following order:

- implement hook node load (load webform components)
- implement hook node view (order webform components into a structure that is hard to modify?)
- create form
- render form using some theming functions

When I use the node preprocessor to alter the components (and attempt to insert a #type = item_list somewhere), it doesn't work. And when using one of the webform theming functions, the data structure comes in a way that is hard to modify. Example:

[image]

That variable that I tried to modify was the `$variables['elements']['webform']['#form']['submitted']` in a **hook_preprocess_node**.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) and look for theming function name.

Comment: The second image in the question is from the variables in the theming function.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the following options

1/ Have a look at the theme functions in webform.module:
* webform_element_wrapper
* theme_webform_element
* theme_webform_element_wrapper

2/ Make use of webform.tpl.php

Or try with jquery/css to alter the whole structure

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to look like a list, you can use css to style it.

```
#webform-client-form-70 .form-item {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: decimal;//for ordered list appearance 
}
```